# couning the number of words occurence in a File

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, arraylist

considering we have `txt` file and we wish to know that how many times each words of the `txt` is appeared. I used the following code but it does not work. it gives all values 1 .
First I read the `txt` file and write each word in a separate line. at the same time, I put them in the Array List. then later, I read first line of the `txt` file and fetch the first element of the Array List and make comparison  with the whole `txt` file. if any occurrence, increasing one to an array that shows the number of occurrence. and then fetching the second Array List item and so on until we reach the end of Array List.

```
 private static void count(String text) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        FileOutputStream thewords=new FileOutputStream(Check);

         ArrayList<String> keyArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
         int countWord=0;

        StringTokenizer tokenizer =new StringTokenizer(text) ;


         while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
         {
             String nextWord=tokenizer.nextToken();
             keyArrayList.add(nextWord);
             thewords.write(nextWord.getBytes());
             thewords.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());


             countWord++;
         }


         int[] numbOfOccurance=new int[countWord];

         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Check));
         String readline;
         for(int loopIndex=0;loopIndex<countWord;loopIndex++)
         {
          readline=br.readLine();
          String test=keyArrayList.get(loopIndex);
            if(test.equals(readline))
            {
                numbOfOccurance[loopIndex]++;

            }

         }
```

Comment: use hashmap<String,Integer> where string will be your words and Integer will be yours counts.

Comment: @Pratik in which line?

Comment: Side note: from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), *StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.*

Comment: read each word of file.....check is it contains in the hashtable if it is then take count from hashmap using your word as a key increase count by 1 and again put it using your word as a key. if its not contains in a hashmap then insert in hashmap using your word as a key and 1 as a count.

Comment: @sp00m so are you telling me that the problem is caused for the sake of `StringTokenizer `?

Comment: @Pratik so you are telling me that at first must put all the words in the hashmap? and all the integers must be 0? then checking like that?

Comment: @lonesome Nop. create hashmap, Start reading your words then check if that word exist in hash map then increase count only else enter word in hashmap and enter default count as 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is incredibly slow, you have to search through the entire `ArrayList` in order to find out if a word appears more than once.

Further, `StringTokenizer` is deprecated.

May I suggest the following approach:

```
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Path path = Paths.get("path", "to", "file");
    final Map<String, Integer> counts = countOccurrences(path);
}

private static Map<String, Integer> countOccurrences(Path path) throws IOException {
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z']+");
    try (final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines
                .flatMap(pattern::splitAsStream)
                .collect(toMap(identity(), w -> 1, Integer::sum));
    }
}
```

This uses the Java 8 [`Stream`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) API to read lines from a file. It then splits the lines on `[^A-Za-z']+`, i.e. non-word, non-apostrophe, characters - using [`flatMap`](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_flatmap_example) to create a `Stream` of individual words.

We then use a [`Map`](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_flatmap_example) to `collect` the words, for each word we put `1` into the `Map`. We then use the merging function `Integer::sum` to add together values already in the `Map`.

You can then list the contents of the `Map`, sorted by occurrence, using the following:

```
counts.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(e -> String.format("%s -> %s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: and very complicated though.

Comment: @lonesome not really. It's 5 lines of condensed code. It's all standard Java API usage, so I reckon anyone familiar with Java would, at a glance, know what this is doing. I can't say the same for your solution. I would strongly advise you to learn the `Stream` API and learn it well...

Comment: thanks. but there is a problem at last line. it says cannot find `toMap`

Comment: now i imprted the library and says the reference in last line is ambiguous.

Comment: ok all my mistakes to add unused import to make the ambiguity. but i cant get the way to get to the stored values from the last three lines.

Comment: so , say, if I want to use these instances in other functions, like finding the min or max occurrence, should I call the function like `counts.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(e -> String.format("%s -> %s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .forEach(computeMin);`

Comment: oh. so it is like that `stream` has it all? that is kind of sweet.

Comment: yea. that is why i deleted my previous comments cause i put the code on a wrong place and the file where not filled at that point. from your code.  am confused about the variable `w`. where did it being declared?

Comment: @lonesome it's a [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)...

Comment: this `Stream` thing needs some serious digging. Meanwhile,  I would like to say thanks for this valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As @Pratik was first to point out, this is a classic use for a `HashMap`.  You only have to go through the list one time.

```
 HashMap<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
 StringTokenizer tokenizer =new StringTokenizer(text) ;

 while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
 {
     String nextWord=tokenizer.nextToken();
     Integer count = wordMap.get(nextWord); 
     if (count  == null){
        wordMap.put(nextWord, 1);
     }
     else{
         wordMap.put(nextWord, count + 1);
     }
 }

 //Print word count
 for (String key : wordMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + " count: " + wordMap.get(key));
 }
```

To address why your current implementation is not working:

I don't think it's feasible to do this with just arrays. With your current code, you create an int array with a size of all words, not the size of distinct words. Even if you were to use an `ArrayList<Integer>` to dynamically add a new entry for each new word encountered, you would need to cycle through the entire list just to process one word. Also, how would you keep a mapping of which word corresponds to which entry in the Integer array?

Comment: that is right. but what is the problem for my code that doesnt count correctly?

Comment: oh. yea. that was the point to be forgotten